# Adding incrementing classname in array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to do this automaticaly (exp I would like to have an array which contains modal-bg1 to modal-bg9...), is there a way to do it ? :

```
var modalBtn = [document.querySelectorAll(".activeModal1"), document.querySelectorAll(".activeModal2")];
var modalBg = [document.querySelector(".modal-bg1"), document.querySelector(".modal-bg2")];
const prevBtn = [document.querySelector("#prevBtn1"), document.querySelector("#prevBtn2")];
const nextBtn = [document.querySelector("#nextBtn1"), document.querySelector("#nextBtn2")];
const carouselSlide = [document.querySelector(".carousel-slide1"), document.querySelector(".carousel-slide2")];
const carouselImages = [document.querySelectorAll(".imgSlide1"),document.querySelectorAll(".imgSlide2")];
```

Comment: "Code Smell" Why do you need this? Maybe if you built code to not need the classname it would go away.

Comment: Because I need to apply a function on each one of those elements, like so : modalBtn.forEach((e)=>{ do smthing with e }))

Comment: So change the code to do look ups inside of the element. If you want to build something that can be used more than once on a page, it is a good idea to build something that works with a single reference so you do not find yourself doing stuff like this that relies on unique identifiers. We can make this work, but there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to handle multiple modals is to let each button know how to query for its own modal i.e. `data-controls`. You can then provide an index e.g. `data-index` to get the correct modal.

All your queries to get the buttons and slides should be relative to the current modal.

```js
const handleClick = e => {
  const
    btn = e.target,
    index = parseInt(btn.dataset.index, 10),
    modal = document.querySelectorAll(btn.dataset.controls)[index];
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(currModal =>
    currModal.classList.toggle('active', currModal === modal));
  
  // Relative queries
  const
    carouselSlide = modal.querySelector('.carousel-slide'),
    carouselImages = modal.querySelector('.carousel-images'),
    prevBtn = modal.querySelector('.prev-btn'),
    nextBtn = modal.querySelector('.next-btn');
};

document.querySelectorAll('.modal-btn').forEach(btn =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  width: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.modal-background {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.carousel-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: grey;
}

.carousel-images {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: lightgrey;
}

.modal-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}

.modal.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="modal-btn" data-controls=".modal" data-index="0">Show 1</button>
  <button class="modal-btn" data-controls=".modal" data-index="1">Show 2</button>
  <button class="modal-btn" data-controls=".modal" data-index="2">Show 3</button>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
      <div class="carousel-images">#1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-buttons">
      <button class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
      <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
      <div class="carousel-images">#2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-buttons">
      <button class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
      <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
      <div class="carousel-images">#3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-buttons">
      <button class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
      <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will take the selector and the amount and generate an array:

```js
function createArray(selector, count) {
    var current = 0;
    var arr = []
    while (++current < count) {
        arr.push(document.querySelector(selector.replace(/\{#\}/g, current)));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

In the selector `{#}` will be replaced with the number:

```js
var modalBtn = createArray(".activeModal{#}");
```

---

EDIT: If you want to have all elements with class `.activeModal` followed by any number, you can simply use the attribute starts with selector:

```js
var modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="activeModal"]');
```

That will return a list of all elements.

Comment: Try educating yourself about template literals. `\`.activeModal${current}\``.

Comment: They cannot be used here, because `createArray` takes a dynamic selector string, and otherwise I would have to use generator functions.

Comment: Thanks ! And what do you put in count parameter ? How do you kind the number of time a class with activeModal appears ?

Comment: `\`${selector}${current}\`` Really no need for string manipulation and regexes here.

Comment: That is exactly the count parameter. If you have 9 elements, you have to set the parameter to 9 etc.

Comment: @connexo what if you want to have the number at different places in the selector?

Comment: Use tagged template strings then.